# Java: Accessing files that are in the same directory as your source file

Tags: java, embedded-resource

1. **How do i access a file that is in the same directory** as my source file? I have seen it done in a tutorial and it was extremely simple, but any searches I conduct on the subject are too broad. any help? i.e.
   `doSomething("file.xml")`
2. **How do I access a file relative to the source file i am working with?** i haven't seen how to do this, but since it would be an acceptable solution for the first question, here it is: i.e.
   `doSomething("src/com.package.file.xml")`

I really just want a platform independent way to access files in my project. I know its probably a duplicate but please don't hate me.

Comment: If you know it is a duplicate then did you search for any similar questions?

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you. =) that was exactly what i was looking for. You should have made that an answer.

Comment: @HopefulLlama I did... my searches were overly broad and too wordy... and i couldn't find any short phrase that would be acceptable

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you shouldn't

Files stored in the `src` directory (especially in Eclipse) won't be accessible at when the application is build and deployed.

Netbeans will package these files as part of your Jar when you build it, Eclipse requires you to these files stored in a separate "resources" directory within the project.

At this point, they become known as "embedded resources" and can no longer be accessed like a normal file, but instead, need to be loaded via the resources functionality available in your class.

For example.

To access the resource in `com/package/file.xml`, you would typically use some thing like...

```
getClass().getResource("/com/package/file.xml");
```

This will return a `URL` which represents the reference to the resource.  If it's more confidnent, you can also gain an `InputStream` directly to the resource using something like...

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/package/file.xml");
```

Which will return an `InputStream` to the named resource...

This all of course, assumes that the resource can be found ;)